# Ударение в слове "Махабхарата"

Tags: фонетика

Здравствуйте!
Я всегда был уверен, что правильно говорить "МахабхарАта" и "РамаЯна", но в последнее время все чаще слышу по телевидению "МахабхАрата" и "РамАяна", и это мне режет слух. Скажите, пожалуйста, как все-таки правильно?

Comment: Те, кто говорят махабхАрата, рамАяна и т. д., путают долготу и ударение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно - как "в последнее время":  Махабх**а**рата и Рам**а**яна,. В санскрите понятие ударения несколько отличается от русского, но в большинстве случаев слова многосложные передаются с ударением на третьем от конца слоге. 
Предпоследний слог - обычное место для ударения при передаче заимствований из большинства языков где нет понятия ударения в привычном нам смысле (японского, например), поэтому понятно стремление использовать вариант, который показался вам правильным.
Но для санскрита этот подход неприменим, поскольку там ударение все-таки есть и не противоречит русской фонетике. Хотя, как сказал, и отличается от русского по сути.

Правда, есть и мнение, что русский язык не обязан следовать источнику. Поэтому в стихотворных, например, текстах могут встретиться и варианты Махабхар**а**та и Рама**я**на. Это не ошибка.

Про ударение в санскрите, смотрите, например, здесь
http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B2_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B5